# how to query get posts filtered with same category in django functional based view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to list out all posts with same catgory on my home page in django. I want title to be category title and then below title it should render all the posts related to that catgory. I did this in class based view by finding help on stackoverflow but I want to know this in functional based view to understand this.

> posts/models.py

```
from tinymce import HTMLField
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from slugger import AutoSlugField
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
User = get_user_model()


def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.slug, filename)


class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    overview = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = HTMLField()
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True, 
        blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    previous_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name= 'previous', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    next_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name= 'next', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

> posts/views.py I tried to do this but this gives me error something like this
>
> TypeError at /
>   index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'category_slug'

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post, Author, Category
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    featured = Post.objects.filter(featured = True)   #put this on carousel
    latest_post = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:6]
    category = Category.objects.filter(slug= category_slug)
    post_by_category = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
    context = {
        'object_list': featured,
        'latest_post': latest_post,
        'post_by_category': post_by_category,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

> urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from posts.views import index
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Is your url catching the query_param? Can you post it?

Comment: @MilesDavis have a look i have edited my question

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code snippet, and  it's totally unclear wether you want posts for one given category or all posts regrouped by category. Please edit your question to fix those points.

Answer (score 0):

when you use a function based view like yours: `def index(request, category_slug):` you are declaring a query_param and you have to catch it in your url. Try this:

```
path('<str:category_slug>', index)
```

as your indexview

Comment: i don't want this i want to render post by categories in homepage

Comment: I think i have to remove that query_params from views function.

Comment: At this line in your code `category = Category.objects.filter(slug= category_slug)`, where you want `category_slug` to come from?

Comment: i want to filter out posts with same category and render it on homepage

Comment: Yes and you have to pass this category to filter against. There is no way to filter by category reading user's mind.

Comment: i want to do something like this have a look here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090076/is-it-possible-to-change-posts-view-as-category-wise-in-django

Comment: I am sorry i am confused i am trying to do this from long while. every tutorial i find they use different page to render posts with category . but the way i want to design is it should be on home page

Comment: Then you have to rewrite your view logic. the queryset must get all the posts in your db. then you can aggregate by category with template tagging in `index.html` if you don't have milion of posts. otherwise you'll have to think at efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

So this will be your url where you get the category slug to filter out the posts

```
path('<str:category_slug>', index)
```

Your request function must have the url parameter as an argument so that you can query the category from the db, in this case it is category_slug

```
def index(request, category_slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)
    post_by_category = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
```

Remember, filter() returns a list of instances, so use get() instead.